# LINQ Where and FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq

```
string[] s = new string[] {"cc", "aa", "bb", "" };
string result = s.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals("aa"));
```

Would one prefer the code above without the .Where() statement or with it?

```
string[] s = new string[] {"cc", "aa", "bb", "" };
string result = s.Where(x => x.Equals("aa")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The former is shorter so I use it, but it's aestetics really.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both forms are equivalent, use the one you prefer. I don't think it makes a big difference in terms of performance... I tend to chose the first form, because it's shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You should really study IQueryable object, it does not work in order you specify. The query is rather optimized by LINQ. There are a lot of tools to scan the result query like LINQPad and others.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the agreement on the coding (code formatting agreement). And no matters for personal use.